# iphone sdk: Can't reuse cell with viewWithTag (can not setText to reused labels)

Tags: iphone, sdk, uitableview

This is my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function. I could not get the `setText` to the label to work. Can you please help me out?

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UILabel *messageLabel = nil;
    int row = [indexPath row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, ROWHEIGHT) reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        messageLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 5, 240, 60)];
        [messageLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:12]];
        [messageLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        [messageLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [messageLabel setNumberOfLines:3];
        [messageLabel setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
        [messageLabel setTag: messageTag];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:messageLabel];

    }
    else{
        messageLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:messageTag];

    }

    [messageLabel setText:[[[aSingleton wallItemArray] objectAtIndex:row] message]];

    NSLog(@" -- > at row %d, message: %@", row, [[[aSingleton wallItemArray] objectAtIndex:row] message]);

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding the UILabel to the cell's `contentView`, but asking the cell for the view.

Have you tried:

```
messageLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:messageTag];
```

EDIT: Also, you have two memory leaks - you're `alloc`'ing a UITableViewCell and a UILabel without (auto)releasing them anywhere.

Comment: Yes I had tried that but I got the runtime error:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[UIView setText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xf4a0c0'

How come it recorgnizes it as a UIView not a UILabel...?

Comment: Ah, in that case you're not getting your original instance back — what's the `messageTag` value set to? If it duplicates another view's tag (for example, all view's tags are zero unless you change them), you'll get the wrong view back.

Comment: U know Ken, I set the messageTag to be 0 and that caused my trouble. I changed it to a random number 342343 and it works!!!! Yeehaaa!!! This problem wasted me so much time until you answered me Ken. Thanks so much! Can I buy you a drink or something :)

"for example, all view's tags are zero unless you change them"
 very valuable info! Thanks Ken!